# Is this expression right?

Tags: grammar

> Even if at the peak of his power he had developed into a local king, his status would not have been equal to that of the Hellenistic kings<

Thanks

Comment: Do you think it's correct? Why or why not? Did you mean to leave that < in there?

Comment: Thanks. I did not mean to leave < in there

Answer (score 1):

I see no grammatical issues with this other than the fact that I would add a period at the end. However, in my opinion, "become" or "been" seem more fitting and natural than "developed into".

> Even if at the peak of his power he had become a local king, his status would not have been equal to that of the Hellenistic kings.
>
> Even if at the peak of his power he had been a local king, his status would not have been equal to that of the Hellenistic kings.

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure it was properly expressed. I will use "become"

Comment: I choose "developed" because I maintain that at first he was just a dynast who gained power and became a local king